# Why should I prefer Azure App Service over .NET REST Web API?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-appservice

Why should I use Azure App Service and not just implement a common .NET RESTful Web API backend?

What's the explicit benefit of this service compared to a common .NET RESTful Web API backend hosted on Azure?

Comment: You need some place to host your API. Azure App Service is one of the options in Azure to do that.

Comment: App Service is a place to host a Web API backend (for example). They aren't two choices for accomplishing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a huge difference between Azure App Service and .Net REST WebAPI backend on Azure.

Hosting on Azure can be done using two ways

1. Create your own VM, then install IIS and do all the required stuff
2. Use AppService Plan

AppService Plan allows you to leverage the powerful functionality of Azure. Here a separate VM is not assigned to you. Azure App service can scale automatically depending upon the Scaling rule which is not present in restful API hosted on Azure VM.

Answer (score 3):

An Azure App Service is a place to host your web application or API. Normally when you have a .NET web API you host it behind IIS or something on a virtual machine.

Azure helps you with these common scenarios wit Platform as a Service (PaaS). An App Service completely abstracts the operating system and the way you host your web application.

App Service can host web apps both on Windows and Linux. You can use all kinds of frameworks such as PHP, .NET or Java. You can even host containers without worrying about the host.

A good sample to start with hosting your .NET Web App on Azure App Services can be found here: [Quickstart: Create an ASP.NET Core web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet)

Answer (score 0):

My question blatantly was a stupid Newbie question, and as such, I'm afraid it is non-sense, which I now know by the answers you've given.

I'm currently reading the book "[Azure and Xamarin Forms](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484235607)" to learn Xamarin and Azure. Apparently it's outdated. It suggests to "create a Mobile App on Azure". From the book that Mobile App is just a plain App Service running a RESTful Web API with EF, but utilizing completely different namespaces to do so.

My question targeted towards these other namespaces. I didn't see a reason for them.

Apparently, Microsoft noticed the same. There is no "Mobile App" available in the Azure Marketplace anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service is a PaaS solution from Microsoft hosted on Azure. You can think of Azure App Service as some sort of "Micrsoft Heroku", because they work on a similar fashion. For many REST Projects, it can save you hours, if not DAYS of development. It has automatic TLS like heroku, but it is hosted on Azure instead of AWS and it can integrate very well with your existing Azure resources. One common pattern is to host the REST API on App Service and use a database service from Azure such as Azure SQL or Cosmos DB (which is a NoSQL service that, from the point of view of your app, it operates as MongoDB, but can be configured to behave as other DBMS).